# active_admin after login redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, activeadmin

i'm having problems with the redirection after the login into active_admin.
The app is redirecting me to the /users/sign_in path.

I've encountered that one way to make the redirection is writing something like that:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    admin_root
end
```

Into the ApplicationController.

The problem is that the after_sign_in_path_for method is already defined with this code (whit user sessions login inside):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    puts "Info: " + resource.to_json
    resource[:is_blocked] ? edit_registration_path(resource) : index_path
end
```

What can i do? The method isn't called when i came from the active_admin login.
Is there any other way to make the redirection?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research, i find the answer.

What i do is (in the application_controller):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 case resource
 when User
  resource[:is_blocked] ? edit_registration_path(resource) : index_path 
 when AdminUser
  admin_root_path
 end
end
```

And also i uncomment this line   **config.sign_out_all_scopes = false**  into the devise initializer, this allows me maintain independently sessions for the different roles.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem adding this code to my application_controller.rb :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || profile_path
end

def admin_access_denied(exception)
  redirect_to admin_root_path, :alert => exception.message
end
```

of course `request.env['omniauth.origin']` and `profile_path` is a path from my application... probably stored_location_for combined with other def will do the job...

regards,